# Creating new BackgroundWorker for every async task

Tags: c#, .net, performance, backgroundworker

I create a new `BackgroundWorker` every time I need to do any Async task and after the work is done I `Dispose` it but I've a doubt if that completely disposes it because the Dispose method is implemented by System.`ComponentModel.Component`

In a typical run of the program, thousands of them may be created. Is it okay if millions of them (to be on the safe side) get created or should I do it some other way?

Most of the async work is I/O and I can't use async/await because I'm using .NET 4 (can't use 4.5).

I've wrapped the whole thing in this method:

```
public void AsyncDo(Action Action, Action ActionFinish = null)
{
    using (BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker()) {
        bw.DoWork += () => Action();
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (ActionFinish != null)
                ActionFinish();
            if (e.Error != null)
                OnException(e.Error);
        };
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

Based on the answers, I've updated it with

```
Task t = new Task(action);
t.Start();
```

But I get a cross-thread error when I do `actionFinish()` by combining it with `action` or calling `t.ContinueWith()`. This wasn't the case in the BGW, it didn't require invoking for `RunWorkerCompleted`. I can't change every call to this method to make them use invoking, what should I do?

Comment: BackgroundWorker is meant only for UI scenarios. Sounds fishy that you would 1000s of them. What kind of GUI is this?

Comment: Don't. Tasks completely replace BackgroundWorker. BackgroundWorker exists only for backwards compatibility and is a lot heavier than Tasks. It's also completely unsuitable for asynchronous work - there is no way to combine asynchronous operations as you can eg witth `async/await`

Comment: What are you tyring to do? There's no reason to use thousands or millions of tasks, much less BackgroundWorkers. To process a lot of data, use Parallel.For or PLINQ. To a strean of requests, use an ActionBlock. To perform work asynchronously behind a UI, use `async/await`.

Comment: What *exactly* is this I/O work? Tasks can be used instead of BackgroundWorker, even in .NET 4.0 ther *are* truly asynchronous I/O methods that will run better than any synchronous method wrapped in a BGW. Weaving multiple tasks is simply impossible with BGW, but can be done with `Task.WaitAll` in .NET 4

Comment: There's no need to spin up new threads to wait on wait handles or asynchronous I/O. Just use the asynchronous APIs, and forget multi-threading. Multi-threading is only useful for CPU work (and the few cases where there *are* no asynchronous APIs for what you're trying to do).

Comment: Are you saying that thousands will run at the same time? That's a lot! Store the work information in a class. Add this object to a FIFO. Have 1 or 2 threads run that periodically check the FIFO for new work to do and execute it.

Comment: @the_lotus Nope, concurrently not more than a dozen will run. But the total number of async tasks will be around thousands.

Comment: Show how you are doing actionFinish()

Comment: @Elmo: Can you use `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`? That would probably be the cleanest solution.

Comment: @StephenCleary Thanks, it's nice but I'd prefer lesser dependencies (I understand I've to install it only once but the current solution works fine so why change it).

Comment: @Elmo: `so why change it` - since you asked, the primary reason is: "to make your code more maintainable." :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BackgroundWorker` is specifically designed to allow code to run in the background with respect to the UI thread, while also allowing simple synchronization with the UI.

If you need to do any async task, just use `Task` - that's what it's designed for. If you don't have .NET 4+, you'll need to use `Thread` (or better, `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`) instead - but that's even more complex (while looking deceptively simple). As always, http://www.albahari.com/threading/ should be your starting point when trying to implement multi-threading (or asynchronous code in general) :)

**EDIT:**

To get a behaviour close to what you had originally with `BackgroundWorker`, you can simply add a continuation to run on the UI thread:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(yourAction);
task.ContinueWith(yourResultAction, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

All of this is strongly typed, so it's quite easy to pass an arbitrary value from the `yourAction` task (running on a worker thread) to the `yourResultAction` task (running on the UI thread). Note that the `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` must be run on the UI thread, of course.

You can wrap this in a simple helper function that will just take the two actions, and return a task (either the original task, or the continuation task - that depends on what you want to do with it).

Also, `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` brings most of .NET 4.5+'s `await` goodness to .NET 4.0 - after all, `await` is all in the compiler, it doesn't need a new runtime to work. Working with `await` is much simpler than working with continuations, especially when doing error handling.

Comment: Actually, BGW is just for compatibility in 4.5. A single Task.Run with Process<T> provide the same functionality.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos BGW is still a component. There's plenty of people who prefer to build their applications using components, rather than functions. Delphi used that to great effect back in the day :) That doesn't mean I would use `BackgroundWorker` - but it's not really obsolete either. There are more ways to skin a cat.

Comment: I usually add BackGroundWorker to a Class and make class IDisposible.  Then I can dispose the class when task is completed.

Comment: @jdweng Well, you don't have to `Dispose` a `Task`. Just sayin'... :D

Comment: @Elmo `Task` has `ContinueWith` to execute an operation after the task is marked as completed.

Answer (score 3):

A race condition occurs when two or more threads access shared data, for writing, at the
same time. (How to deal with race conditions is covered later in this chapter in the “Synchronizing
Resources” section.) If you try to update the UI from another thread, .NET Framework throws an
InvalidOperationException containing the following message: "Cross-thread operation not
valid: Control 'ctrlName' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was
created on."

To solve the problem, change the worker_RunWorkerCompleted method
as follows:

```
void _worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
        if (this.InvokeRequired) {
            this.Invoke(
                new Action(ActionFinish));
        }
        else {
            ActionFinish();
        }
    }
```

In the worker_RunWorkerCompleted method, you now check the InvokeRequired
property. This property is defined in the Control class, and as such is present on all the controls on a page. InvokeRequired is set to false if you call it from the UI thread and true
otherwise.

The Invoke method takes as the first parameter a delegate, meaning any method can be
placed there. The new Action() constructor call is used to make sure that you
get a delegate. If your method has a different signature, you must change that constructor
accordingly. The rest of the parameters of the Invoke method are sent directly to the method
you want to run. Invoke places the method call in a queue to be picked up by the UI thread.

A better solution ?

```
void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e { this.Dispatcher.Invoke(()=> //statement); }
```

It is enough to call the Dispatcher.Invoke method in all the situations. This call
ensures that the lambda expression ()=> //statement is run by the UI thread,
regardless from which thread the method is called.

Answer (score -4):

A BackgroundWorker and a task are both windows processes so I don't know why you need both.  A class is also a process, but I like using a separate class rather than a task.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim backgroundWorker As New MyBackGroundWorker
        backgroundWorker.Dispose()
    End Sub

End Module
Class MyBackGroundWorker : Implements IDisposable

    Dim backgroundWorker As New BackgroundWorker

    Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose

        Me.Dispose()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I don't understand. Your class implements nothing new, it's the same as a normal BGW, a normal BGW also implements IDisposable that's why you can call `.Dispose()`

Comment: With my method you can also dispose other object associate with the backgroundWorker in the class dispose method.  My method will dispose all objects in the class.

Comment: (I wasn't the downvoter) Yeah but your answer doesn't add anything new.

Comment: @Elmo Why didn't you? I see no value in this post. I'm sorry for being so honest jdweng, but did you get *anything* right in this post? Bgws, tasks and classes are processes now? Why doesn't your custom bgw dispose the wrapped bgw? And finally, why do you suggest code which ends with a big bang aka. a [StackOverflowException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception(v=vs.110).aspx)? I've seen you post better answers than this ;)